# My LED circuit stops working after a bit

Tags: led, rectifier

So I built a rectifier circuit for my bike to use with the dynamo and placed an LED at the end of it.

The LED has these ratings:
- Power: 2W
- Rated voltage: DC 3.0V~3.2V
- Rated current: 600~650mA
- Brightness: 160~180LM
- Color temperature: 2850~3050K

The bottle dynamo is an AXA HR Traction with these specs
- Power: 3W
- Rated voltage: AC 6.0V
- Rated current: 500mA

I built the rectifier circuit with 4x1N4004 schotty diodes.

Now my problem is that it works perfectly fine for the first few minutes but after a bit, the light goes out and simultaneously drains all power from the rear light as well.
So does anyone know why it does this? I know I might have fouled something up, but I am fairly new to all of this, so bear with me. :P

Comment: And did you add a resistor to limit the current?

Comment: Please add the relevant schematic.

Comment: No I did not add a resistor, could that be the problem?

Comment: Does the circuit start working again when you let everything 'cool down' for a while and try again? Or is it definitively broken?

Comment: It starts working again once it cools down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamo produces 6v (nominal), the rectifiers drop 1.2V (2 x 0.6V) leaving 4.8V for the LED which exceeds the maximum rating. Its not a particularly good idea to run the LED at its maximum current especially if the supply could vary (as in a dynamo output). So choose a safer 'operating' current, say 300mA, which is below the maximum for the LED and dynamo.

[image]

This gives a value of resistance needed as    1.8V/0.3 = **6 ohms**

The power rating for this resistor should be   0.3^2 * 6 = 0.54W - so **use a 1W resistor** to keep it cool.

Comment: Maybe you have something I could read that clarifies why exactly this is?
So if I get it right, I need a 1W 6Ohm resistor?

Comment: @Kris look at http://ledsmagazine.com/features/4/8/1

Comment: So I kinda have a dumb question, seeing as the best my local shops can do is either 0.25W or 10W resistors, would it work to serially couple a few 0.25W resistors or is as bad an idea as it sounds?

Comment: @kris Personally I go for four resistors (24R, 0.25W) in parallel rather than serial.

Comment: So here is how I get a little confused again, why does some resistors have the ohm listed on the package and some R100 or so?

Comment: @Kris Most resistors use colour coded bands (black = 0, brown = 1 etc.) When putting a value for a resistor in a **circuit diagram** you identify it e.g. R1, R2 etc. and give it a numerical value 10R = 10 ohms, 100R = 100 ohms, 1k0 = 1000 ohms, 2M2 = 2200000 ohms. Sometimes manufacturers just print a value onto the resistor (especially if it is a low value). Surface mount resistors have a number code system so 333 means 33 000 (33k) - Whatever system is used the important things are the value, tolerance and power rating.

Comment: Thank you, makes quite a bit more sense now. But how does 4x 24Ohm resistors make sense then?